# CSS3 Animation not working in any browsers

Tags: css, sprite, css-animations

I am using a sprite along with CSS3 animation in an attempt to make a rollover. It works somewhat in CODA 2 however when i test in Mozilla, Chrome, Safari and Opera the animation does not occur.

```
/*linkedin contact button*/
button{text-indent:-99999px; border: none; }
a.linkedin,a.linkedin:hover{display: block; cursor: pointer; background: url(../img/linked.png) no-repeat; width: 128px; height: 128px}
a.linkedin{background-position: -0 -0}
a.linkedin:hover{animation:first 1000s; -moz-animation:first 1000s; -webkit-animation:first 1000s; -o-animation:first 1000s;}

@keyframes first{from {background-position: -140px -0;} to {background-position: -0px -0;}}
@-moz-keyframes first{from {background-position: -140px -0;} to {background-position: -0 -0;}}
@-webkit-keyframes first{from {background-position: -140px -0;} to {background-position: -0 -0;}}
@-o-keyframes first{from {background-position: -140px -0;} to {background-position: -0 -0;}}
*a.linkedin:hover{background-position: -140px -0/9}/*for ie*/
```

Comment: Please also add some HTML, or even better, provide an example in http://jsfiddle.net/. The css alone is hard to debug.

Comment: For 0 you can leave out units though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the CSS3 transitions? If all you do is change the background position creating keyframes is kind of overdoing it. See this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RfbhD/3/

All the CSS you need:

```
a.linkedin {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/128) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 128px; 
    height: 128px; 

    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s ease; 
       -moz-transition: background-position 1s ease; 
         -o-transition: background-position 1s ease; 
            transition: background-position 1s ease; 
}

a.linkedin:hover{
    background-position: -140px 0; 
}
```

​